# Function to modify all elements instead of one in C

Tags: c

I'm very bad with C. I have to create a function that saves a name from a file into an array. My code seems like it is working, but when I `printf` at the end of the function, all elements are the last name on the list.

```
void Names(char *Txt, char **Array) {
  FILE *Text;
  Text = fopen(Txt, "r");
  int a = 0;
  int Buffer = 150;
  char string[150];
  char Buff[25];
  while (fgets(string, Buffer, Text) != NULL) {
    strcpy(Buff, strtok(string, " ,\n"));
    Array[a] = Buff;
        printf("%s\n";Array[a]);
        a++;
  }
  int c = 0;
  while (c < a) {
        printf("%s\n", Array[c]);
        c++;
  }
}
```

The first while prints all names like it should, but the second doesn't.

The first one prints `name1,name2,name3,name4`, and the second one prints `name4,name4,name4,name4`.

Comment: You only have one buffer, which you store a pointer to, but the buffer content is overwitten by each line. You need to allocate memory and copy the actual text. For example `Array[a] = strdup(Buff);` if supported by your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just assign pointer to buff here

> `Array[a]=Buff`

That is you have ptr to Buff in every Array element.
You must allocate new array to Array[n] instead of use Buff.

> `strcpy(Buff,strtok(string," ,\n")); Array[a]=Buff;`

Remove Buff var and replace this piece by

```
Array[a] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
strcopy(Array[a], strtok(string," ,\n"));
```

It could help.

Comment: And don't forget to check fopen ret value

Comment: please don't cast result of `malloc()`, try not to use `sizeof(char)` because it is always 1 by definition.